# $locationChangeStart is not working in firefox

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, on-location-changed

$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

```
        if (!$rootScope.isPopupOpen) {

            if ($rootScope.isUrlLoad) {

               window.location.reload();

            }
        }

        $rootScope.isUrlLoad = true;

    });

In other browser,i have no problem for loading..But in firefox it continuously loading.can anyone please suggest me?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem it's probably related to the fact `$locationChangeStart` it's called even the first time your page load.

Simply get rid of this issue with a flag:

```
var firstTime = true;
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

    if(firstTime){
       firstTime = false;
       event.preventDefault();
       return;
    }

    if (!$rootScope.isPopupOpen) {

        if ($rootScope.isUrlLoad) {

           window.location.reload();

        }
    }
    $rootScope.isUrlLoad = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion